# In xcode 4.3.3 is there a keyboard shortcut to switch between the Organizer and the IDE?

Tags: xcode, ide

I'm new to Mac.. i've figured out command+tab switches between applications.. but after two months, I haven't figured out how to switch between the Organizer and the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (command-shift-2) to launch the organizer and (command-w) to close any active window. You can then use (command-`)<-tilde as stated above to switch between active windows in any open application in OS X, including Xcode.

Comment: command-` isn't specific to Xcode, it's a Mac OS X shortcut. It gives you the next window in the stack.

Comment: @MarkThalman Ahhh, good to know! I've never used it in any other application besides Xcode.

Comment: @user1405352 If this answer has helped you be sure to mark it as correct by clicking the "check mark" next to this answer.

Comment: this is quite strange... it worked initially, but now it isn't working (Command+`).

Comment: @user1405352 How many windows do you have opened? This will only work if there are multiple Xcode windows currently open. And if this answered your question you can mark it as correct by selecting the "check mark" next to this answer.

Comment: interesting... it Command+` only works if the windows are 'zoomed' (i.e., the red, yellow, and green buttons in upper left are visible)... if one or the other is full screen(?), then Command+` has no effect.

Comment: @user1405352 Sorry, that is correct, I forgot to mention that. Additionally, once you have windows in fullscreen, you can navigate between them using (command-left arrow) or (command-right arrow)

Comment: huh?  Command+left/right arrow seems to just move the cursor to the beginning/end of the current code line in an 'editor' window, and in the Organizer window, it seems to do nothing.  (by full screen, I mean I have clicked the grey arrows in the upper-right corner, and their background is now blue.

Comment: @DoYouLikeHam sorry again! I've been up for quite a while! I meant control.